# Need to decrease response time using postfix

Tags: php, sockets, smtp, postfix-mta

> I have one script in PHP to connect mail server using a socket with
>   use of fsockopen for Gmail, Yahoo, Hostgator based mail address.
>
> Once a socket connection is successful, I have to read data from that.
>   When reading data for Gmail, Yahoo it returns within 1 second, while
>   Hostgator and others take 5 seconds to read data.
>
> So, my concern is that how can I reduce the time.
>
> Following is my script :

```
<?php

$mx = 'gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com';     // It takes only 200ms
//$mx = 'imailv.emirates.net.ae';       // It takes only 400ms
//$mx = 'mail.trantech.com';            // It takes around 6000ms(Problem is 
                                          here)

$handle = @fsockopen($mx, 25 , $errno, $errstr, 5);
echo fgets($handle);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solution won't fit your workflow, but you could use a Mail Sending Service (such as SendGrid, Amazon SES) that will allow you to:

- Send bulk email
- Use an HTTP API (instead of SMTP)
- Have way better throughput (probably) than you would ever achieve with your PHP Script + Infrastructure

Comment: Actually, I didn't send an email. I just ping to the recipient mail server.